# Keeping only the cases with non-zero observations in a fixed effects regression

Tags: stata, panel-data

I'm currently working with SOEP panel data (years 2002 through 2010) and I've run into a bit of trouble. I'm trying to run a fixed effects regression with child allowance as the dependent variable and person year as the independent variable. I would only like to include individuals who have given their child an allowance for at least one year in the sample. I assume that individuals who *did not* give their child an allowance at any point during this time span are automatically dropped since fixed effects regression measures within variation and doesn't include individuals with no variation in a given variable (think cohort). That would be my question: Does `xtreg, dvar ivar1 ivar2 ivarx, fe vce(cluster id)` automatically drop individuals with no variation in a given variable, or do I have to manually drop them from the regression? If so, how would I drop those individuals?

**Edit:**

I would only like to drop individuals who do not provide their children any allowance during the observation period, while including those who do at least once. I ended up using the following code:

```
*Generate variable for cases with at least one non-zero value over the observation period 
bysort id (year): egen sumofallowance= sum(childallowance) 

*Run a fixed effects regression using this variable as a condition.
xtreg childallowance idyear if sumofallowance>0, fe vce(cluster id)
```

I was unsure whether Stata would automatically do this, and it turns out Stata does not as I have about 9,000 fewer observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know your sample that you want to run your regression on it is always a good idea to restrict your regression to that sample explicitly. Especially if you do not have very precise understanding on how the command you are using deals with no variation, missing values etc. If you want your work to be reproducible then this is a good practice to use even if you understand how the command works as it makes your code more readable for other people who might not understand this command as well.

I would suggest that you create a variable called something like `sample` that you set to 1 for all observations that you want to include in the regression and then restrict `xtreg` to that sample. In your case it would be something like this:

```
*Create a variable that is 1 for the intended sample
gen sample = (dvar > 0 & !missing(dvar)) // Sets sample = 1 if non-zero and non-missing, otherwise set to 0

*Run regression restricted to sample
xtreg dvar ivar1 ivar2 ivarx if sample == 1, fe vce(cluster id)
```

You might have to edit the line that generate `sample` depending on the format of the data in `dvar`.

Finally, `xtreg` could drop observations for other reasons, so make sure that the N in the regressions match the number of 1 you get in `tab sample, m` and make sure that this also match your expectation of the sample you have in mind.

Comment: Thank you for this feedback! I'm a student and still learning Stata and this was helpful. I've figured out a way to include observations with at least one non-zero value since I would still like to keep people in the sample who might have given no allowance at one point during the observation period (see edit).

Comment: Nice adaptation! However, one comment since you seem to be eager to learn best practices. Be concision about naming practices. Now the values in variable `sample` is a sum but anyone reading your code would expect a dummy. How about `bysort id (year): egen sum_childallowance = total(childallowance)` (`total()` gives you what you want not `sum()` see `help egen`) and then `gen sample = (sum_childallowance > 0 & !missing(sum_childallowance))`. This makes your code a bit longer but much more readable which is good practice in research. Also, please upvote and accept my answer if it was helpful

Comment: I actually did name the variable "childallowancesum" but kept it general here in case anyone was looking for generic code. Also, I don't have enough 'reputation' to upvote, but Stack Overflow says my feedback was noted!

Comment: ok, great. Thanks for accepting answer. You should still change `sum()` to `total()`. `sum()` is a running summary which only sums the rows above that row and not all rows for that ID. `total()` sums all rows for that ID. See example towards bottom of `help egen` that explains this. Then I still recommend the intermediate step of `sample` with the `!missing(sumofallowance)`  as then you handle missing values better as `sumofallowance>0` will include missing value in `sumofallowance`. Such obs will be excluded as `childallowance` will be missing for that row, but better to be explicit.